# Words highlighting when talking

Tags: video, animation

Is there any automatic way to make words highlight when talking? For example, when I display the phrase `Join the StackExchange community`, each `word` of the phrase is `highlighted` as I say it. I see many videos with this feature on tiktok, but I wanna make youtube video.
I use canva pro and davinci resolve free version to edit my videos.
Of course I can do this manually but its hard to synchronize voice with displayed text.

Like in the photos below

[image]

[image]